# Office 365/Excel Online, connect to on-prem SSAS Tabular?

Tags: excel, sharepoint, office365, ssas-tabular

I have an on-premise ssas tabular cube, and a nice excel front end that connects to it with slicers etc.

I would like to put that excel front end on our O365 sharepoint, and have it function there - data refresh/interactive and so forth.

How is this accomplished? Right now I just get the message "External data refresh failed" when I click on a slicer or anything.

Thanks for any tips,
sff